# Segmentation fault in scanning values in Dynamic array ( int **arr)

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, malloc, dynamic-arrays

This code Giving a segmentation fault. On debugging by GDB it is giving this error:

> "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007ffff7a6dde5 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=, 
>       format=, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdba8, 
>       errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1902 1902   vfscanf.c: No such file or directory. "

```
void  readData()
{
int **arr,m;
scanf("%d",&m);
arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
    arr[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
    printf("..%d ..\n",i); // if m = 20 then running only 12 times
    scanf("%d %d",&arr[i][0],&arr[i][1]);

    }
}

int main()
{
readData();
}
```

**If m=20 then, Second loop is only running 12 times and then giving segmentation fault. While first loop is running 20 times.**
Please Help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
```

This should be

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);
```

since you need to allocate `m` pointers, not `m` ints.  Or better,

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr)*m);
```

(By the way, don't cast the result of malloc.)

Comment: `int (*arr)[2] = malloc(m * sizeof *arr);` ... and then *the entire array* is allocated as one, rather than as `m+1` calls to `malloc` :)

Answer (score 3):

Following line has a problem

```
arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
```

you are allocating sizeof(int) times m, this should be changed to sizeof(int *)*m to hold addresses rather than int (these might be of different sizes and can cause problem). So this should be as below

```
scanf("%d",&m);
arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*m);
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
```